# Vue 3 - get access to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm migrate Vue 2 to Vue 3.
I'm using ag-grid and using buttons in every each row and these button using methods from parent component.
In Vue 2 The syntax was simple: this.$parent.$parent (I'm usind twice $parent because of Ag-Grid)
But now I'm facing with the Vue 3 and I want to getting the same component to work and doesn't have any idea how to write it.

I'm glad for helping

This is the code where I'm actually doing this:

```js
<template>
  <div class="main">
    <i class="fa fa-info icons" @click="infoButton"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-file icons" @click="filesHistoryButton"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-edit icons" @click="editReminderButton"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import defineComponent from "vue";
import { getCurrentInstance } from "vue";
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Actions",
  setup(){
    const instace = getCurrentInstance();
    
    console.log(instace.parent.parent)
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {},
  beforeMount() {},
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    infoButton() {
      this.$parent.$parent.GetNotificationHistory(this.params.data.id);
    },
    filesHistoryButton() {
      this.$parent.$parent.GetFilesLists(this.params.data.id);
    },
    editReminderButton() {
      this.$parent.$parent.EditReminder(this.params.data.id);
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: It's expected to be the same in Vue 3. Is it about composition api? Then the question is asked incorrectly, because you can use composition api in V2, and you can use options api in V3. I'd expect it to work with composition api as `instance.proxy.$parent.$parent`. The use of $parent is a really bad practice, you can consider it an opportunity to refactor it to a better design

Comment: did you figure that out? having the same problem - it seems like $parent behaviour had changed in Vue 3 as my code stopped working. Seems like $parent is now referencing to something else, but can't figure out what exactly (damn "proxy" obscures things)

Answer (score 1):

The [`$parent`](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#parent) property should work with Vue 3 ether.

Be sure you don't use the [expose](https://vuejs.org/api/options-state.html#expose) declaration in your parent components, that limits the accessibility of your methods.

Like Estus Flask already said, this is not recommended practice, since it creates tight coupling between your components.

It would be much better to use custom events to interact with parent components.
See the Vue Docs about [Component Events](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html#component-events)

Like this:

```
export default defineComponent({
  name: "Actions",
  emits: ['infoButton','filesHistoryButton','editReminderButton'], // <--- define events
  setup(){
    const instace = getCurrentInstance();
    
    console.log(instace.parent.parent)
  },
  data() {
    return {};
  },
  computed: {},
  beforeMount() {},
  mounted() {},
  methods: {
    infoButton() {
      this.$parent.$parent.GetNotificationHistory(this.params.data.id);
      this.$emit('infoButton', this.params.data.id);
    },
    filesHistoryButton() {
      this.$parent.$parent.GetFilesLists(this.params.data.id);
      this.$emit('filesHistoryButton', this.params.data.id);

    },
    editReminderButton() {
      this.$parent.$parent.EditReminder(this.params.data.id);
      this.$emit('editReminderButton', this.params.data.id);
    }
  }
});
```

And in the parent component accordingly:

```
@info-button="GetNotificationHistory"
```

Comment: The way it needs to be implemented may depend on the case, since this requires a parent to be able to pass through events to a grandparent. The actual solution may depend on third-party component in use (Ag-Grid).

Comment: what's the composable API?

Comment: There are [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) and [Composition API](https://vuejs.org/guide/introduction.html#api-styles). No Composable API